# Populate dropdown with SQL Query, append value to begining of array , and echo selected

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I want to create a drop-down using a SQL query, append "All" as first option text with a value of "" or add it to the beginning of the array and then have the drop-down remember the selection after I post.  This is my code:

```
<label for="formMeet">Meet:</label>
<?php
$query_meet = "SELECT distinct Meet FROM `RESULTS_final` order by Date DESC";
$meetlist = mysql_query($query_meet);
array_unshift($meetlist, "All");
echo "<select name='formMeet'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($meetlist)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['Meet'] . "';
    if($_POST['formMeet'] == $row['Meet'])
        echo "selected = 'selected'";
    echo ">" . $row['Meet'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

I broke the code trying to echo the selected results and array_unshift is not working to append "All" to the beginning of my list.  The enumerated version of the drop-down looks like this:

```
<label for="formMeet">Meet:</label>
<select name="formMeet">
<option value="">All</option>
<option value="TEAM5 & TEAM4 @ TEAM3 7/19/2016" <?php if($_POST['formMeet'] == "TEAM5 & TEAM4 @ TEAM3 7/19/2016") { echo "selected=\"selected\""; } ?>>TEAM5 & TEAM4 @ TEAM3 7/19/2016</option>
<option value="TEAM2 @ TEAM1 7/19/2016" <?php if($_POST['formMeet'] == "TEAM2 @ TEAM1 7/19/2016") { echo "selected=\"selected\""; } ?>>TEAM2 @ TEAM1 7/19/2016</option>
<option value="TEAM2 @ TEAM5 7/12/2016" <?php if($_POST['formMeet'] == "TEAM2 @ TEAM5 7/12/2016") { echo "selected=\"selected\""; } ?>>TEAM2 @ TEAM5 7/12/2016</option>
<option value="TEAM4 @ TEAM3 7/12/2016" <?php if($_POST['formMeet'] == "TEAM4 @ TEAM3 7/12/2016") { echo "selected=\"selected\""; } ?>>TEAM4 @ TEAM3 7/12/2016</option>
<option value="TEAM5 @ TEAM4 7/5/2016" <?php if($_POST['formMeet'] == "TEAM5 @ TEAM4 7/5/2016") { echo "selected=\"selected\""; } ?>>TEAM5 @ TEAM4 7/5/2016</option>
<option value="TEAM3 @ TEAM1 7/5/2016" <?php if($_POST['formMeet'] == "TEAM3 @ TEAM1 7/5/2016") { echo "selected=\"selected\""; } ?>>TEAM3 @ TEAM1 7/5/2016</option>
</select>
```

It works, but since there are always new meets, I would like to use the database to populate the drop-down.

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do `mysql_fetch_array($meetlist)` before adding All to the array, so something like this:

```
<?php
    $query_meet = "SELECT distinct Meet FROM `RESULTS_final` order by Date DESC";
    $meetlist = mysql_query($query_meet);
    $rows = mysql_fetch_array($meetlist);
    array_unshift($rows, array("Meet" => "All"));
    echo "<select name='formMeet'>";
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        echo "<option value='" . $row['Meet'] . "';
        if($_POST['formMeet'] == $row['Meet'])
            echo "selected = 'selected'";
        echo ">" . $row['Meet'] . "</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first code is almost correct. When you retrieve result from mysql_query function its not returns an array it returns a resource. I expect you may get error on array_unshift function. You can iterate on resource and create array and add "All" option after but this approach may consume valuable resource. So mixing your both approach will fix this issue better as the following code:

```
<label for="formMeet">Meet:</label>
<?php
$query_meet = "SELECT distinct Meet FROM `RESULTS_final` order by Date DESC";
$meetlist = mysql_query($query_meet);
// array_unshift($meetlist, "All");
echo "<select name='formMeet'>";
echo     "<option value="">All</option>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($meetlist)) {

echo "<option value='" . $row['Meet'] . "';
if($_POST['formMeet'] == $row['Meet'])
echo "selected = 'selected'";
echo ">" . $row['Meet'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

Please do not hesitate to ask anything. Hope helps!

Comment: I think this is close.  A couple of things.  You notice I'm cheating a bit ALL in my enumerated list and setting the value to NULL when ALL is selected.  This is because I'm using the values as criteria in a select query.  Is there a way I can do that?  Also, I'm getting an error with my syntax around "if($_POST['formMeet'] == $row['Meet'])" - do you see something obviously wrong with my syntax?  Thanks for taking the time to respond.  Really appreciate the help.

Comment: This is the error on that line: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

Comment: This is a syntax error .Please change with following comment

Comment: .  echo "<option value='" . $row['Meet'] . "'";
    if($_POST['formMeet'] == $row['Meet'])
        echo "selected = 'selected'";
    echo ">" . $row['Meet'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";